# TFS Integration Platform: How to map users with the SVN adapter?

Tags: tfs, tfsintegrationplatform

I want to migrate sourcecode from SVN to TFS2010 using the TFS Integration Platform.

I am using the Codeplex Release from March 25th of the TFS Integration Platform.

The SVN Adapter basically works. I can get the sourcecode from the SVN repository into TFS, including the full history (all revisions from SVN).

However all the checkins into TFS are done as the user that is running the TFS Integration Platform Shell.

I was wondering how I can configure a mapping of SVN users to TFS users.
My SVN users are not ActiveDirectory of configured as Windows users.

I would just like to specify an explicit mapping for each SVN user to an existing TFS user.

On the web I found several hints at using a `<UserMappings>` element or a `<ValueMap name="UserMap">` or an `<AliasMappings>` ... but there seems no concrete example how to configure that with the SVN adapter. All my experiments are failing...

Is this supposed to work with the SVN adapter?

Could somebody give me a hint or a pointer how to configure this mapping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok the guys over at the TFS Integration Platform MSDN forum [provided the solution](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsintegration/thread/3e35cb27-6733-44a3-b364-936951288427).

I just repeat it here:

Add or extend the `<UserIdentityMappings>` element in your configuration xml. This element is inside the `<SessionGroup>`. It sould lokk something like this:

```
<UserIdentityMappings EnableValidation="false">
   <UserIdentityLookupAddins />
   <DisplayNameMappings DirectionOfMapping="LeftToRight">
      <DisplayNameMapping Left="svnuser1" Right="domain\user1" MappingRule="SimpleReplacement" />
      <DisplayNameMapping Left="svnuser2" Right="domain\user2" MappingRule="SimpleReplacement" />
   </DisplayNameMappings>
</UserIdentityMappings>
```

This worked form me.