# TFS Integration Platform Migration Issue access denied

Tags: tfs, tfsintegrationplatform

Here is the scenario:
I have 2 TFS servers, TFS-A is in local and TFS-B is abroad.
Check into TFS-B is very slowly, so my idea is to check into TFS-A first, 
and check all changes into TFS-B from TFS-A in once time at night.
But the TFS-A and TFS-B have different user accounts, when I synchronize them, error happens.
The error told me access denied.
So if it is possible to sync two TFS with different accounts.
How to do it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to supply a **user mapping** in your TFS integration platform configuration. A similar post shows how to do this in detail: [TFS Integration Platform: How to map users with the SVN adapter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939243/tfs-integration-platform-how-to-map-users-with-the-svn-adapter)

Hope that helps you further.

Comment: Although it is SVN sync to TFS, not TFS to TFS, but it's a good way to find the similiar solution. thanks a lot. I'm finding the soluting following your way.

Comment: You can apply the same mechanism for TFS to TFS synchronization.